# Database error in Android from create method

Tags: java, android

I get this logcat error:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id=0

This my code:

```
public static final String dbName="notesDb";
public static final Integer DB_version=1;

public static final String key_id="id";
public static final String key_title="title";
public static final String key_subject="subject";

public static final String Table_notes="notes";
```

public DbNotes(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, DB_version);

```
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String create_table="create table "+Table_notes+"("+key_id+"Integer primary key,"+key_title+" varchar(30), "+key_subject+" varchar(50)) ";
    db.execSQL(create_table);
}

public Note getNoteByID(int id){
    Note note=null;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery="SELECT * FROM "+Table_notes+" WHERE "+key_id+"="+id;
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        String title=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(key_title));
        String subject=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(key_subject));
        int id_item=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(key_id));
        note=new Note(title,subject,id_item);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return note;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Which part of the error is confusing you? Table `notes` does not have a column named `id`.

Comment: public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create_table="create table "+Table_notes+"("+key_id+"Integer primary key,"+key_title+" varchar(30), "+key_subject+" varchar(50)) ";
        db.execSQL(create_table);
    }     Is there  mistake in create  method?

Comment: As I said, the table doesn't have a column named `id`. Since you're missing space between `id` and `Integer`, you have a column named `idInteger` without a declared type. Voted to close as the problem is caused by a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in your `Create` query, you need to provide appropriate space after column name.

`"create table "+Table_notes+"("+key_id+" Integer primary key," // you missed space before Integer`

So sqlite will create your column with name `idInteger` and not `id`, You can try using select query by referring `id` column as `idInteger`.

Comment: I got same error after adding space ( no such column: id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id=0)